# Get img source from js Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a js object `slider.controlNav`, that contains DOM elements. I need to save in variable source of image, that contains in link with class `'flex-active'`.

```
 jQuery.each(slider.controlNav, function(i, val) {
   var  dom_object = slider.controlNav.get(i);
      console.log(dom_object)
  });
```

Top code returns:

```
<a href="#0" class="flex-active">
    <img src="img/slider-portfolio/logos/__ico__Fason$Active.png">
</a>

<a href="#1>
    <img src="img/slider-portfolio/logos/__ico__Web$Active.png">
</a>

<a href="#2" class="flex-active">
    <img src="img/slider-portfolio/logos/__ico__New$Active.png">
</a>
```

My code:

```
jQuery.each(slider.controlNav, function(i, val) {
   var  dom_object = slider.controlNav.get(i).find('img').attr('src');
      console.log(dom_object)
  });
```

After that in console i have error:

> Uncaught TypeError: slider.controlNav.get(...).find is not a function

Comment: You probably need `$(val).find('img').attr('src')` instead

Comment: show `console.log($(val).html())`

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this?

Answer (score 0):

`get` function gives you the underlying DOM object. You need to convert it to jQuery object.

Try `$(slider.controlNav.get(i)).find('img').attr('src');`

Comment: You've missed the first and first and foremost the last line in the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this code.

```
jQuery("slider.controlNav a").each(function() {
    var  dom_object = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src');
    console.log(dom_object)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do want to use `this` or `val`, which refers to the current element in the iteration:

```
jQuery.each(slider.controlNav, function(i, val) {
    var  src = jQuery(this).eq(i).find('img').attr('src');
    console.log( src )
});
```

Alternatively, just use plain JS as follows:

```
slider.controlNav.forEach(function(val) {
    var src = val.querySelector( 'img' ).src;
    console.log( src );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ruqohuxuma/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
var flexActiveControlNavs = slider.controlNav.find(".flex-active");

jQuery.each(flexActiveControlNavs, function(i, val) {
   var dom_object = flexActiveControlNavs.eq(i).find('img').attr('src');
   console.log(dom_object);
});
```

This will return only the image sources that are a child of elements with class "flex-active".